# Como meter asincronia dentro de una función con async-await en angular 7

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular, async-await

Buen día, esta es mi primer pregunta así que espero poder darme a entender, estoy trabajando con angular 7, y estoy haciendo una función que ejecute un servicio, pero 10 veces al mismo tiempo, y una vez que esas 10 ejecuciones finalicen, se genere un reporte.

Estoy utilizando async-await con promesas, pero esto se me complica a la hora de la ejecución de los 10 llamados en paralelo, ya que no veo forma de regresar valor en el await, por tanto, nunca pasa de esa función.

¿Alguien sabe de alguna manera de poder avanzar?

Esta es la estructura de mi codigo.

```
async ejecucionParalelo(){
    //Ejecutamos la funcion ejecutarServicios(), para que cuando termine se comience a ejecutar la funcion de generarReporte()
  try{
     await this.ejecutarServicios(datos);
     await this.generarReporte();
  }
}

//Aqui se ejecutan los 10 servicios de forma paralela
ejecucionParalelo(){
  this.services.ejecutarServicio(datos: Datos[]);
  this.services.ejecutarServicio(datos: Datos[]);
  this.services.ejecutarServicio(datos: Datos[]);
  .
  .
  .
}
```

El problema es que no se como verificar que las 10 ejecuciones en paralelo hayan finalizado, para que el código pueda avanzar a la generación del reporte.

Espero me hayan entendido y gracias de antemano por el apoyo.

Answer (score 0):

```js
// crear diferentes promesas
function operacionAsincrona(numero){
  // retorna una nueva promesa que terminará luego de un timeout
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
    setTimeout(resolve, 1000, numero); 
  }); 

}

// arreglo de promesas que se ejecutarán en paralelo
let arregloPromesas = [
      operacionAsincrona(1),
      operacionAsincrona(2),
      operacionAsincrona(3),
      operacionAsincrona(4),
]


// Promise.all  se cumple cuando todas las promesas del iterable dado 
// se han cumplido, o es rechazada si alguna promesa no se cumple
Promise.all(arregloPromesas).then(values => { 
  // aquí se puede generar el reporte
  // todos los procesos terminaron
}, reason => {
  // en caso de error
});
```